# Service Application will not stay running

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am building an application monitoring service to write to the event log so I can get an general Idea how often the computer is being used. I can install the service and when I try to run it I get this error:

"The Application Monitor service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the performance logs and alerts service."

I've tried a while loop, mouse activity, and etc... but it keeps ending. any ideas on what I can do?

```
    public ApplicationMonitor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Activity Usage"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("Activity Usage", "Computer Log");
        }

        eventLog1.Source = "Activity Usage";
        eventLog1.Log = "Computer Log";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop.");
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnContinue.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no active thread.

You need to start your thread that does the polling in the "OnStart" method of your service.  Otherwise when the OnStart method completes, there is no active thread in the application and the .Net CLR will close the app.

Even if the thread is simply doing a thread sleep every 30 seconds, it must be alive in order for the app to stay open.